# Combining multiple saved Classifier in weka

Tags: java, c#, machine-learning, weka

Have huge distributed datasets which are trained to produce classifiers.All the datasets have identical attributes and the training is done using a single algorithm J48.
The problem I am facing is as to how would  combine these classifiers to have a single classifier which can be used for testing and predicting data.
I am using weka tool for the code.Have converted the weka jar to dll.Using C# language.
Any help in C# or Java would be of great help.
If any additional information is needed you are free to ask.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to do what you are asking for. You could build N different classifiers from N different but compatible datasets and combine their outputs to form a new dataset of higher order. Its a hierarchical way of combining classifiers and there is a great variety in ways of doing that. Its called 'ensembling' or 'classifier ensemble'. There are a large number of technical articles detailing how to do it.

One approach would be:
1. Train/get N different classifiers.
2. Build a new dataset with its probability output for a known set of instances, one instance per row, the set-of-output-probalities per set of columns. And the right/known class.
3. Throw away the old attributes and retain only the output probs calculated and known class.
4. Train a new model/classifier with this higher order dataset (don't need to use the whole data, only a moderate subsample).
5. For every new instance, get lower level probabilities (using N classifiers), as previously done, and apply higher level classifier over these newly constructed instance.

Hope to have helped.

Comment: By the way, using different classifiers over different but compatible datasets tends to reduce the prediction error, improving the general model. It's mathematically proved in different technical articles. It's the basis for the methods known as 'bagging', 'boosting', etc, which are particular cases of 'ensembling'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible if you create N classifiers on N training sets and then combine N classifiers to generate a single one. Because first, the data are different; second, so the models will be different. Instead, what I would do is if I were happy with the N results, I would combine all N datasets and develop a single model from it to test and predict unseen data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.However my work is targeting a distributed environment.So the large datatsets would be distributed and each such distributed environment would produce its own classifier which would be sent to a central control which in turn would combine them.The approach you mentioned would not be feasible because we are targeting very large datasets here accounting to terabytes of data and it would be a huge overhead transporting these to the central server.Any other options for this?

Comment: Did you keep ensembles or majority voting of classifiers in mind?